Error in DrawROI() : could not find function "DrawROI" in r version 4.3.3
Error in DrawROI() : could not find function "DrawROI"
The function DrawROI() allows the
user to draw one or more regions of interest on-screen, using the
mouse cursor on a chosen reference picture. pl. resolve
tried installing Phenopix but DrawRoi could not be found out.

It seems like the function was renamed in {phenopix} v2.4, c.f. ?DrawMULTIROI():

This function allows to draw one (or more) region(s) of interest (ROI) on a jpeg image. After phenopix version 2.4 this function allows to draw a region of interest potentially consisting of different polygons.

